# Unity List view which stretches to fill remaining space available screen space

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to make a file browser control for unity.  Everything works fine when I'm using my standard resolution.

[image]

However when I Change resolutions the inner box is not flexable. so the scroll bar and list view will overlap the bottom footer or leave too much space

[image]

My header is a fixed height of 150 and my footer controls is a fixed height of 280. Honestly I'd preffer If I could figure out a way to make those not fixed as well. So that they would take up top 10% of screen and bottom 18% of screen

The inner list view box should expand to consume the remaining space.

I know I could write a script to do all of this but with the new UI I'm almost sure there is a way to do it with the built in components.

Does anyone know how I can make my Panels and all of its children act as a flex box?

Comment: Incase anyone was wonder, I solved this, by setting the anchor points so the the inner box will be flexible

Comment: Correct anchors are the way to go! Also take a look at the mighty [Canvas Scaler](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-CanvasScaler.html)